# Creating Array From Multidimensional Array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

In my Cakephp Form I am Selecting Students And multiple documents. My Problem is that I can Create Student Array Fine But Can't able to create the same for uploaded file.
i am getting the values in this format

```
[student_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
$student=['1','2'];


$filename= array(
  array(
    "tmp_name" => "C:\xampp\tmp\phpC542.tmp",
    "error" => "0",
    "name" => "file1.pdf",
    "type" => "application/pdf",
    "size" => "410922"
  ),
  array(
    "tmp_name" => "C:\xampp\tmp\phpC562.tmp",
    "error" => "0",
    "name" => "file2.pdf",
    "type" => "application/pdf",
    "size" => "410922"
  ),
  array(
    "tmp_name" => "C:\xampp\tmp\phpC545.tmp",
    "error" => "0",
    "name" => "file3.pdf",
    "type" => "application/pdf",
    "size" => "410922"
  )
);
[filename] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php53EE.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [name] => file1.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [size] => 403993
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php53FE.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [name] => file2.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [size] => 410922
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php541F.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [name] => file3.pdf
                [type] => application/pdf
                [size] => 846448
            )

    )
```

I want to create the Array in the following format.

```
[students] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 2
            )

    )
[files] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [filename] => file1.pdf              
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [filename] => file2.pdf              
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [filename] => file3.pdf
            )
    )
```

I am Using the following to get my array. I am successfully getting the results on student array but having problem with generating filename array and saving each file in server.
My code is

```
$data=$this->request->getData();
$studentids=$data['student_id'];
$students=array();
foreach($studentidsas $studentids){
    $key=array('student_id');
    array_push($students,array_fill_keys($key, $studentids));
}
$files=$data['filename'];
$file=array();
foreach($files as $files){
    $key=array('filename');
    array_push($file,array_fill_keys($key, $files));
    move_uploaded_file($data['filename']['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT.'pdffiles//'.$filename);
}
```

Any Help will Really Appreciated i am really stuck in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a var_export of the first array?

Comment: It Doesn't work i tried.

Comment: well then this is a good day to get fimiliar with it. var_export i just like var_dump or print_r but we can copy paste your array instead of retyping everything. I don't like to type that massive array maually, if you do then feel free to edit your question to such state that we can copy your data.

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: You did not read what I wrote.

Comment: Edited with the array variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_push($file,array_fill_keys($key, $files['name']));
```

if you give the field you want to fill your **array** with, it will work

Comment: move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT.'pdffiles//'.$filename); or as i would do move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT.'pdffiles//'.$files['name']);